# How do I write React Functional Component + TypeScript's function overloading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function

I know how to write React Functional Component and TypeScript + function overloading.

But when these two are combined together, I am confused!

Here is a minimum code example to illustrate what I want to do:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';

type PropType1 = { type: 'type1'; name: string };
type PropType2 = { type: 'type2'; age: number };

// How do I properly hook FunctionComponent + PropType1 + PropType2?
// It's called FunctionComponent right?

function Example({ type, name, age }) {
  if (name === undefined) {
    return (
      <div>
        {type}, {age}
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        {type}, {name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default Example
```

This example's usage should look like this:

```
<Example type="type1" name="Joseph"/>
// => <div> type1, Joseph </div>

<Example type="type2" age={18}/>
// => <div> type2, 18 </div>

<Example type="type3" name="Joseph" age={18}/>
// => Compile Error!
```

How do I properly hook FunctionComponent + PropType1 + PropType2?

And, it's called FunctionComponent right?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) and check the props type in component.

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';

type PropType1 = { type: 'type1'; name: string };
type PropType2 = { type: 'type2'; age: number };

function Example(props: PropType1 | PropType2) {
  if (props.type === 'type1') {
    return (
      <div>
        {props.type}, {props.name}
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        {props.type}, {props.age}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

Usage

```
<Example type="type1" name="Joseph"/>
// => <div> type1, Joseph </div>

<Example type="type2" age={18}/>
// => <div> type2, 18 </div>

<Example type="type3" name="Joseph" age={18}/>
// => Compile Error: Type '"type3"' is not assignable to type '"type1" | "type2"'

<Example type="type1" age={18}/>
// => Compile Error
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-kda5tx)

Comment: That seems working! Thank you, I will wait a few more seconds if there are actually function overloading implementation solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`FC`](https://github.com/fi3ework/blog/tree/master/react-typescript-cheatsheet-cn#%E6%97%A0%E7%8A%B6%E6%80%81%E7%BB%84%E4%BB%B6), functional component, with [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types).

`FC` type provides some extra properties, e.g. `displayName`, `defaultProps` and so on, to make your functional component more type safe.

`Union` type can provide similar functionality of function overloading. It limits the combination of properties, which choice either `PropType1` or `PropType2`

```js
const Example: FC<PropType1 | PropType2> = (props) => {
  if (props.type === 'type1') {
    return (
      <div>
        {props.type}, {props.name}
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        {props.type}, {props.age}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by myself

```
import React, {
    PropsWithChildren,
    ReactElement
} from 'react';

type PropType1 = { type: 'type1'; name: string };
type PropType2 = { type: 'type2'; age: number };

function Example(props: PropsWithChildren<PropType1>): ReactElement | null;
function Example(props: PropsWithChildren<PropType2>): ReactElement | null;

function Example(props: {
  type: 'type1' | 'type2';
  name?: string;
  age?: number
}) {

  const {type, name, age} = props

  if (name === undefined) {
    return (
      <div>
        {type}, {age}
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        {type}, {name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default Example
```